# Create variables for each group specified in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to use data.table to compute variables for each group specified. For the sake of simplicity, let's say the data is split according to groups in x1:

```
x1  x2
a   3
a   4
b   1
b   5
```

And I want to create a variable for the mean of each group but I dont know how to index each group:

```
DT[,list(
    mean_a=mean(x2) #for all rows containing "a"
    mean_b=mean(x2) #for all rows containing "b"
  by="x1")]
```

How can I rewrite the lines with comments? (i.e. find the mean for all rows with "a", same for "b")

I need the output as a data.table in separate columns, as it will be processed further:

```
mean_a  mean_b
3.5     3
```

EDIT: after playing around with it, here is the solution I wanted.

```
> DT2=DT[,list(
+     mean_a=mean(x[grep("a",x1),x2]),
+     mean_b=mean(x[grep("b",x1),x2])),
+     by=NULL]
> 
> DT2
   mean_a mean_b
1:    3.5      3
```

It's not as efficient as Frank's but it's what I asked for originally, i.e. to rewrite the lines with comments.

Comment: `dt[, mean(x2), by = x1]`??? Can you update your question to clarify what you're actually trying to ask, and, if necessary, also show a sample of the output you expect.

Comment: Ananda's comment works but shows the result in rows and not in columns like in your example.  Do you need it in columns?

Comment: In case that's the case, you can use `dt[,mean(x2),by=x1][,{names(V1) <- paste("mean_",x1,sep=""); V1}]`, just adding an extra step onto Ananda's answer/comment.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to get the output in a data.table with multiple columns. Frank's solution only provides the names of the variables. Furthermore, it would be good to have the flexibility of naming each variable separately as I did (has to do with the specifics of my data).

Comment: Okay, I've offered an answer. By the way, neither your example input nor the output actually look like a data.table (you know, with the `1:` at the beginning of the first line and so on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's worth your while to set names separately for each value of `x1`, just choose an appropriate prefix:

```
dt[,mean(x2),by=x1][,{
    names(V1) <- paste("mean_",x1,sep="")
    do.call(data.table,as.list(V1))
}]
```

However, if you really want custom names, you can put them into a vector beforehand:

```
mynames <- c(
a = "mean_a",
b = "mean_b"
)

dt[,mean(x2),by=x1][,{
    names(V1) <- mynames[x1]
    do.call(data.table,as.list(V1))
}]
```

The result is

```
   mean_a mean_b
1:    3.5      3
```

**EDIT**: As @eddi pointed out, this is a better way of doing the same thing:

```
setnames(dt[,mean(x2),keyby=x1][, as.list(V1)], sort(mynames))
```

If you assign this somewhere, you will see that it is the desired `data.table`. You can also get it to print by appending `[]` at the end of the call or by putting the whole thing in parentheses.

Comment: this is better imo: `setnames(dt[,mean(x2),by=x1][, as.list(V1)], mynames)`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the value of `setnames` is a `data.table`. Your answer is much cleaner. I'll edit it in at the end.

Comment: @eddi Does that depend on `mynames` having the same order as the `x1` column generated by the `by=x1`? I guess `by=x1` is just ordered by first appearance...?

Comment: if you use `keyby` instead of `by`, the result you get will be sorted (as it will key and then do a `by`), otherwise it will be as is

Comment: Ok, thanks for the effort. When I first posted this problem, I had a similar solution:
    `dt[,mean_=mean(x2),by=x1]
    dt2 <- split(dt, mean)
    colnames(d2) <- c("mean_a","mean_b")`
But I felt that there was a way to do this within the actual data.table expression without having to resort to additional functions. So, just to clarify, there is no way to embellish the code specified with comments so that I can create variables only for rows containing "" (some string). Nothing perhaps with grep()?

Comment: I think I'm not understanding you. `by=x1` groups by rows containing each unique value of `x1`. `setnames` is a `data.table` function, so that last option is a `data.table` expression.

Comment: This is probably a very inefficient solution: `vals <- c(a_mean = "a", b_mean = "b"); dt[,lapply(vals,function(z)mean(x2[x1==z]))]`.

Comment: Frank, your solution is fine and I will accept it, but I was simply hoping there was a way to do it all within the DT expression itself, especially the naming of each variable.

Comment: Well, of course, the two-liner from my last comment can be made more awful: `dt[,lapply(c(a_mean = "a", b_mean = "b"),function(z)mean(x2[x1==z]))]`. Now, it's all in the `dt[` call. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain there's a more elegant solution, but this works:

```
x1 <- c('a','a','b','b')
x2 <- c(3,4,1,5)

df=data.frame(as.factor(x1),x2)
groupmeans = sapply(unique(x1), function(x) {mean(df[x1==x,]$x2)})

#   a    b
# 3.5  3.0

groupmeans_table = data.table(t(groupmeans))

#       a  b
# 1:  3.5  3
```